# Parameters for the SPJobDefintion constructor

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What are parameters for the SPJobDefintion constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better answer to this question than the original MSDN documentation: [SPJobDefinition Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition.spjobdefinition.aspx)